# Verilog preprocessor string concatenation

Tags: verilog

I am trying to use a Verilog preprocessor macro in Altera Quartus requiring use of a parameter value inside a variable name.

Example:

```
`define INCREMENT_COUNTER(parsername) \
__parsername_counter <= __parsername_counter + 4'h1;
```

So using  `` `INCREMENT_COUNTER(p1) `` should give

```
__p1_counter <= __p1_counter + 4'h1;
```

However `parsername` is not properly replaced and returns

```
__parsername_counter <= __parsername_counter + 4'h1;
```

I have also tried using

```
__``parsername``_counter <= __``parsername``_counter + 4'h1;
```

which doesn't work either.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

``` `` ``` works in VCS and Incisive, but I don't know about Quartus:

```
module tb;

reg clk = 0;
always #5 clk = ~clk;

reg [3:0] __foo_counter = 0;

`define INC_CNT(name) __``name``_counter <= __``name``_counter + 1;

always @(posedge clk) `INC_CNT(foo)

initial begin
    $monitor($time, " clk=%b cnt=%d", clk, __foo_counter);
    #55 $finish;
end

endmodule
```

Outputs:

```
                   0 clk=0 cnt= 0
                   5 clk=1 cnt= 1
                  10 clk=0 cnt= 1
                  15 clk=1 cnt= 2
                  20 clk=0 cnt= 2
                  25 clk=1 cnt= 3
                  30 clk=0 cnt= 3
                  35 clk=1 cnt= 4
                  40 clk=0 cnt= 4
                  45 clk=1 cnt= 5
                  50 clk=0 cnt= 5
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit old, but the correct answer is that concatenation is available till SystemVerilog.

So if someone wants to use it:
Settings->Analysys & Synthesis Settings->Verilog HDL and check the SystemVerilog

Some of simulators may use it regardless of the choosen standard (like Icarus), which might be a little confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use `{"a","b"}` syntax to concatenate in a macro with params.

For example:

```
`define DEFAULT_CS_PATH(x,y) {"../../../fpgas/cs/", x, "/build/tmp/scalar", y, ".mif"}

cs20_top #(
               .SCALAR_MEM_0 (`DEFAULT_CS_PATH("cs20","0")),
               .SCALAR_MEM_1 (`DEFAULT_CS_PATH("cs20","1")),
               .SCALAR_MEM_2 (`DEFAULT_CS_PATH("cs20","2")),
               .SCALAR_MEM_3 (`DEFAULT_CS_PATH("cs20","3")))
        cs20_top (
            .CLK                (clk),

            ...
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this out:

```
`define PHANTOM(x) x
`define INCREMENT_COUNTER(parsername) \
__`PHANTOM(parsername)_counter <= __`PHANTOM(parsername)_counter + 4'h1;
```

It works for me on `Verilator 4.210 2021-07-07 rev v4.210`