# Is it possible to append the value of macro argument instead of appending it literally?

Tags: macros, verilog

I have a macro that I would like to use in the following fashion:

```
`define assign_m(CH, INT_NUM) \
    assign dp_input``CH``_if.master_mp.sigA[INT_NUM] = some_signal[CH][INT_NUM];

generate
   for(genvar i=0; i<2; i++) begin
      for(genvar j=0; j<2; j++) begin
         `assign_m(i,j)
      end
   end
endgenerate
```

I would like to have a construct like this to expand to:

> ```
> assign dp_input0_if.master_mp.sigA[0] = some_signal[0][0];
> assign dp_input0_if.master_mp.sigA[1] = some_signal[0][1];
> assign dp_input1_if.master_mp.sigA[0] = some_signal[1][0];
> assign dp_input1_if.master_mp.sigA[1] = some_signal[1][1];
> ```

But of course it doesn't happen that way as Verilog literally appends the variable `j` instead of its value (§ 22.5 *`define, `undef, and `undefineall* of [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf), page 644).

**How can I have a macro where the argument's value is appended?**

Comment: I think this is similar to [Verilog preprocessor string concatenation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26288793/97073).

Comment: I am doing the same concatenation in the example shown in my question. The problem is that I am limited by the way the concatenation functionality is implemented as per the IEEE standard and I am looking for a work-around. From my example, if I manually do `\`assign_m(0,0)`, `\`assign_m(0,1)`, `\`assign_m(1,0)`, `\`assign_m(1,1)`, it works. In my actual use case, I would need to do something similar for 16x10 times. The `generate for` as shown in the example will save me that trouble but then `\`assign_m(i,j)` ends up with **literal** substitution.

Answer (score 0):

If `dp_input_if` can be created as an array and an indexed version used, then it could be written out as:

```
integer i;
integer j;

always @* begin
  for(i=0; i<2; i++) begin
    for(j=0; j<2; j++) begin
       dp_input_if[i].master_mp.sigA[j] = some_signal[i][j];
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I am using arrays in my test bench so that I can use macros on them in a loop. But there is some RTL which I can't modify (IP/legacy); in there the signal and module names have `_NUMBER` suffix.